# Logical fault in repeat-while loop?

Tags: swift, loops, swift4

I have a problem with the repeat-while loop.I dont know why it doesnt work at my code.Maybe i have some logical fault.

```
func getJson(){
    repeat{
         movieName.isHidden = true
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(128188))

        let jsonUrlString = "https://api.url/3/movie/" + String(randomNumber) + "?api_key="

        //let jsonUrlString = "https://api.url.org/3/movie/564?api_key=key&language=de-DE"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else
        {return}

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in

        guard let data = data else {return}

        let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print(dataString ?? String())

        strTrue = false
```

Here I'm checking if the api returns some data if not they will give me a status code 34.Im checking for the word "status code".
If the api returns "status_code". I'm checking it with a if and then I turn string-code to true.So the condition of the repeat-while loop is 
then string-code is true he will start it again and looking for a new movie id.But I tested it and it doesn't work. Maybe you guys can help me :)

```
        let stringCode = dataString?.contains("status_code")
        if stringCode == true {
            print("yes fehler 34")

            strTrue = stringCode!
            print(strTrue)
        }            

        do {

            guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else {return}

            let movie = Movie(json: json)

            print(movie.name)
            print(movie.genres)

            let imageString = "https://image.url.org/t/p/w500"+(movie.imageUrl)
            let url2 = URL(string: imageString)
            //self.movieImage.downloadedFrom(url: url2!)

            self.movieDescriptionLabel = movie.overview
            self.movieNameLabel = movie.name


            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.movieName.isHidden = false
                self.movieName.text = self.movieNameLabel
                self.movieDescription.text = self.movieDescriptionLabel
                self.movieImage.downloadedFrom(url: url2!)

            }

        } catch let jsonError {
            print("Error",jsonError)
            self.getJson()
        }

        }.resume()
    }while(strTrue == true)
```

Comment: You are missing the fact that the URLSession call is async. That's why your while test doesn't work.

Comment: hmm ok can you explain me how to fix this ? :)

Comment: Don't use the repeat/do/while. Just call your own method (recursivity) if the result isn't correct?

Comment: ok thank you i will try it.